# Configure redis as cache

Tags: redis

I want to use redis purely as cache. what options do i have to disable in redis.conf for ensuring so . I read that by default redis persists data (AOF and rdb files and perhaps more). Is that true for even the keys which are set to expire.
Isnt it contradictory to persist data that is set to expire?

Answer (score 0):

Redis stores all its data in RAM, but dumps it to the persistent storage (HDD/SDD) from time to time. This procedure is called snapshotting.

You could configure snapshotting frequency in [your `redis.conf` file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antirez/redis/2.8/redis.conf) (see `SNAPSHOTTING` section):

```
#   save <seconds> <changes>
#
#   Will save the DB if both the given number of seconds and the given
#   number of write operations against the DB occurred.
#
#   In the example below the behaviour will be to save:
#   after 900 sec (15 min) if at least 1 key changed
#   after 300 sec (5 min) if at least 10 keys changed
#   after 60 sec if at least 10000 keys changed
#
#   Note: you can disable saving completely by commenting out all "save" lines.
#
#   It is also possible to remove all the previously configured save
#   points by adding a save directive with a single empty string argument
#   like in the following example:
#
#   save ""

save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
```

So, if you want to disable snapshotting completely, you should remove or comment all `save` directives in `redis.conf` file.

Comment: ok recently i stumbled across this 

[link]http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-persistence-demystified.html  

which says that "RDB snapshots are also used by Redis when performing a master -> slave synchronization."
So if i disable snapshotting would that stop my master-slave sync?!

Also any idea how to disable AOF persistence ,i tried setting "appendonly" to no , but am not sure if that is sufficient.
Also apart from Snapshotting and append only related parameters (in redis.conf )are the any other  things/parameters i need to take care of?

Comment: Redis uses snapshots to perform **initial** synchronization. Disabling RDB snapshots will only disable automatic snapshotting, it won't affect commands like `SYNC` (replication) or `BGSAVE` (manual snapshotting).

Comment: As for AOF, it should be enough to set `appendonly` to `no`, though it's not enabled in redis default configuration, anyway.